# Повторное открытие Activity

Tags: java, android, xamarin

Есть у меня приложение, которое содержит в себе несколько экранов. Нужно сделать навигацию между этими экранами. Прилепил вот такие кнопочки на два экрана.
[image]
На первом экране на кнопку далее повесил событие:

```
Intent productIntent = new Intent(this, typeof(ProductsActivity));
StartActivity(productIntent);
```

На второй форме, на кнопку назад:

```
OnBackPressed();
```

Соответственно получается, если на второй форме я добавил какие-то данные в список, жму "Назад", перехожу на предыдущий экран, жму "Далее" и на сколько я понимаю, у меня создается и открывается новый "второй" экран с пустым списком.
Как сделать, чтоб прогресс с "второго" экрана не пропадал?

Если бы я писал аналогичный код на c# winform, то он выглядел бы примерно так:

```
    Form m_form = null;

    private void M_forwardButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(m_form == null)
        {
            m_form = new Form();
        }
        m_form.Show();
    }
```

Comment: О гайдлайнах под платформу вы наверное не слышали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/activity.php

Цитата: "Для передачи данных в другую активность используется метод `putExtra()`:

```
intent.putExtra("Ключ", "Значение");
```

Принимающая активность должна вызвать какой-нибудь подходящий метод: `getIntExtra(), getStringExtra()` и т.д.:

```
int count = getIntent().getIntExtra("name", 0);
```

"

Конец цитаты.

Comment: То есть, перед закрытием второй activity, нужно передать все данные из неё в первую activity, а при повторном запуске второй, заново все инициализировать?

Comment: Именно так. Интенты для того и существуют, чтобы сообщать о том, что мы намерены сделать и  с какими ресурсами.